# What is the best VPN for Mac/Windows/Linux Server

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vpn, mac-osx

I have had bad luck when using hamachi, and I am looking for a good vpn that works on any network, and on Mac 10.6, Windows 7, and Ubuntu Linux Server.

I've looked into OpenVPN but was way too complicated to even get working.

Comment: I managed to set up OpenVPN over a Verizon MiFi, while on a 40 minute morning train ride.  That included getting Tunnelblick running as a client on MacOSX as well as configuring my firewall.  It's really not hard at all.  If your IT guy can't do it, get a new one or do it yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best VPN for Mac/Windows/Linux Server](http://serverfault.com/questions/71725/what-is-the-best-vpn-for-mac-windows-linux-server)

Answer (score 5):

OpenVPN is the "best" VPN for Mac/Windows/Linux.  The idea that it is "too complicated" is a false one; whilst it may not be herp-a-derp simple, it's a whole lot simpler to setup than any other alternative.  IPSec is a veritable hell's kitchen in comparison to OpenVPN, which is about 6 lines of config.

Comment: The too complicated came from my IT guy, I am a front end developer so this is beyond my expertise, I am just doing research rather than random google searching.

Comment: If your IT guy thinks that OpenVPN is too complicated, it's time to get a new IT guy.

Comment: Maybe he just doesn't *want* to set it up :-)

Comment: Then he gets to propose a superior alternative, install what's he told, or find a new job.  Prima donna bullshit doesn't fly with me.

Comment: OpenVPN is *simple*. +1 for get a new IT guy.

Comment: He could have meant that it was too complicated for end users.  Also note that running openvpn on the command line, with no arguments, shows about 10 pages of options.  Also refer to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17447/answer-or-comment-whats-the-etiquette

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your situation, you might want to rethink setting up openVPN on two Linux servers and have them act as gateways for the two networks, or using two router boxes that support VPN's to each other (like cisco systems, I don't know if any SOHO routers support this kind of setup).

If you're doing this on a small network, using the VPN solution on dedicated routers would be a good solution. I'd personally investigate bootable routers based on Linux for setting up ipsec.

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4772

http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2006/06/06/openvpn-vs-vpn-router/

[http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:*Ch35*:_Configuring_Linux_VPNs](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch35_:_Configuring_Linux_VPNs)

Or use some google-fu to find something like "linux router vpn" or "linux bootable vpn", or some variant thereof.

Answer (score 0):

I like openVPN...do you mean the client is hard to set up as in hard for end users to set up on their machines?

I found it easier to make an installer for openVPN using [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)

using that I setup the openVPN client with the right cert(s) and config file...then compile it to one installer for the end user

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. openvpn on debian server (start with easy default setup...)
2. viscosity on OS X clients from http://www.viscosityvpn.com/
3. and our PC-Guys use the GUI from http://openvpn.se/

Answer (score 0):

Cisco ASA5505 and the AnyConnect client works great... but it is a bit expensive. We use it with all version of linux, mac and windows without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you find OpenVPN too confusing, you're pretty much stuck with hamachi, go2mypc and similar services. I don't beleive there are any serious multi platform VPN solutions available that are any simpler to set up.

I hear Steve Gibson has an upcoming product, Cryptolink which aims to be a very easy and functional VPN solution for home use. No idea when it will be available, though.

I suggest having another go at OpenVPN, it's not that hard once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

I have setup openVPN on a consumer grade Linksys WRT-54g router.  It works great and you don't need a seperate server for the VPN endpoint.  To do it, you need to flash the router with DD-WRT and then re-flash it with an image that includes openVPN.  Be careful though, it is quite possible to brick the router if you don't follow the instructions carefully.

Troubleshooting is a bit tricky, but it can be done if your admin is familiar with TCP/IP routing and bridging.

I started by first installing the endpoint on Linux.  It is much easier to troubleshoot.