# What is the best VPN for Mac/Windows/Linux Server

Tags: linux, windows, vpn, mac

I have had bad luck when using hamachi, and I am looking for a good vpn that works on any network, and on Mac 10.6, Windows 7, and Ubuntu Linux Server.

I've looked into OpenVPN but was way too complicated to even get working.

Comment: you won't get VPN more easily than with OpenVPN. Belongs to serverfault.

Answer (score 5):

Well that may be because VPN technology is not that easy...  OK the OpenVPN docs are probably a bit too long, but there are plenty of easy step by step explanations on how top set it up available on the net.  Did you try one of these?  Like [this one](http://www.thebakershome.net/openvpn_tutorial) or [this one](http://theillustratednetwork.mvps.org/OpenVPN/OpenVPN-Installation.pdf) or [this one](http://www.adamsinfo.com/quick-linux-and-windows-openvpn-howto-and-tutorial-including-vpn-routing/)

Comment: I will look into these, I have 2 Macs, 2 ubuntu servers and a few windows pc's and we are using Hamachi, but outside the main network the connection on a mac drops out in a matter of minutes.

Comment: I think this has ended up duplicating. Anyway, if you're connecting networks, use a gateway that uses VPNs or set up appliances to do it. Then it doesn't matter if you're using Mac/Linux/Windows. It's done at the network level. The other question has some links to research bootable Linux routers and distro stuff for setting it up more easily.

Comment: OpenVPN has awesome cross-platform compatibility. For your MAC, use Viscosity. It costs less then 10$ and does OpenVPN very well with a pretty GUI.

Comment: the first two links now give 404 errors

Comment: All three links are dead/404.

Answer (score 1):

OpenVPN is a great solution, but OpenVPN Access Server is even better. It's easy to install with pre-compiled binary packages, and a breeze to setup with the use of a web interface. It does require a license though. They give you two concurrent connections for free, and then charge $10 per connection afterwards. The clients can log into a web portal that then provides client binaries and instructions on how to set the client up. It's easy to configure and powerful, feature rich, as well as simple to understand. Check it out.

I blogged about it here: http://jordaneunson.com/?p=74

Check out OpenVPN Access Server here: http://www.openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/download-openvpn-as.html

Comment: +1 for OpenVPN-AS, it's easy to get up and running and tremendously easy to deploy -- it creates windows client install files with configs built right into the exe, customized for each user, available when they log in to the web interface. Simply run the file and install is complete -- no configuration necessary. Not as good for site-to-site deployments, but for mobile users it's the best $50 we've spent in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another vote for OpenVPN. While it may at first appear slightly daunting the job is made very much simpler by using one of the GUI interfaces for it. There's Tunnelblick for the Mac but I don't recall the names of the Windows and Linux GUIs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a relatively easy way to get openVPN up and running, the [OpenVPN module on pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org) is pretty good, and it can also do PPTP and IPSec.  All 3 are easy to configure through the web interface, and the whole thing is very easy to install and configure form scratch.  Hardware requirements are pretty low, and pfSense also has lots of other packages and modules available in addition to the core firewall.

Answer (score 0):

SoftEther VPN is a good option.  It's an open-source alternative to OpenVPN that claims to have better performance.  I've been using it with Windows on the server side and macOS and Windows 10 clients.  (For the Mac it is also configured for L2TP over IPSec.)

https://www.softether.org/